# Fixing a certain year in datepicker in android

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I want to fix a certain range of year in datepicker. I only want that range of the year.

I only have the DatePickerDialog object and a OnDateSetListener object, how do I incorporate a datepicker into this arrangement?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please also provide some more information so that our experts can give more detailed and appropriate answers. It would be helpful to include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Try getting the `DatePicker` from the dialog using `DatePickerDialog.getDatePicker()` and then using `DatePicker.setMaxDate()` and `DatePicker.setMinDate()`

Comment: It is worth noting that getDatePicker() is only from API 11.